# How to access specific values along with single key from Javascript associate array using for in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is the associative array with multiple values for single key

```
var course ={170:["Introduction to Programming"," Develop algorithms forcomputers",5],
250:[" Web Development","Build web applications",3]};
```

I want to display key who have one of its value ==3
that is, ***`250:[" Web Development","Build web applications",3]};`***

using for in loop.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A generic approach

```js
    
    var course ={170:["Introduction to Programming"," Develop algorithms forcomputers",5],
250:[" Web Development","Build web applications",3]};
    
    function printKey(value, arr) {
        for(var i in arr) {
            if(arr.hasOwnProperty(i) && arr[i].indexOf(value) > -1) {
                console.log(arr[i])
            }
        }
    }
    
    printKey(3, course);
```

Comment: Good to include a *hasOwnProperty* test, an explanation would have been even better. ;-)

Comment: "The hasOwnProperty method which returns a boolean indicating whether the object has specified property". Here I'm checking if the object has the property and the object which contains the value as well.

Comment: I meant an overall explanation of how your algorithm works, not just *hasOwnProperty*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var course ={170:["Introduction to Programming"," Develop algorithms forcomputers",5],
250:[" Web Development","Build web applications",3]};

for (key in course) { // repeat for each key
    if (~course[key].indexOf(3)) { // check if 3 is in array
        console.log(key); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulations on saving two characters with `~`. [*includes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) uses the same number of characters but is more semantic. ;-)